# Static IP error in Ubuntu 12.04.03 LTS

Tags: networking, static-ip

I am getting the following message after changing dhcp to start with the following settings:

```
Address 192.168.1.24
network mask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway 192.168.1.1
```

> *Running /etc/init.d/networking restart is deprecated because it may 
>   not enable again some interfaces
>   *Reconfiguring network interfaces...

what does deprecated mean? I have searched the blogs and none is helping

Comment: Use `sudo service networking restart` or `sudo restart networking`, because old syntax becomes deprecated which means it comes out of using.

Comment: Thanks danatela when I restart using suggest syntax above I get the MSG "stop: Unknown instance: networking / waiting. Please note that I am able to ping my dns and websites

Comment: @Given To clarify, 'deprecated' in terms of commands means that the referenced command is no longer officially supported and has been replaced with a newer command string. This is usually because script libraries and code has changed to invoke new functions not implemented in the old command string.

Answer (score 0):

**Just do one change**

network give 192.168.1.0/24

Hope this will help you

Comment: Daniel are you saying I type the network IP exactly with .0/24?

Comment: @Given Yes, enter `network 192.168.0.0/24` - this enables access to the entire subnet.

Comment: @douggro I have done as daniel suggested and when I do Sudo service restart networking restart , I get "stop: Unknown instance: networking stop/waiting" what does this exactly mean? I want to proceed and install Samba. Can i go ahead?

Comment: @Given See my answer to your other question.

Answer (score 0):

auto eth1

iface eth1 inet static

address 192.168.1.24

netmask 255.255.255.0

network 192.168.1.0

broadcast 192.168.1.255

gateway 192.168.1.1

After edited, try this command " sudo ifup eth1 "

Try like this, it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Deprecated means that it's  not used anymore instead you can use other commands like:

```
sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0
```

replace eth0 with your interface

or

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```